# PHP: form validation "Full name"

Tags: php

Right now i have this for full name:

```
if(empty($_POST['full_name']) || strlen($_POST['full_name']) < 4)
{
$errormessage[] = "ERROR.\n";
}
```

How can i make a validation for full name, so the entered name should contain space?

So like if person enter:

> John Andersson

Its ok, but if he enter:

> JohnAndersson

its not ok, error. So you would need a "space" in your fullname.

Comment: I don't think this is wise. The convention that first name and last name are separated by a space character doesn't apply to all the world's languages.

Comment: this is for a community in my local city

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (strpos(trim($_POST['full_name']), ' ') !== false){
  // user has specified first and last name
}
elseif (strpos(trim($_POST['full_name']), ' ') !== true){
  // user has specified a single name
}
```

You need to enter the `trim` function to check for bad names such as:

- `Justin Alba[space]`
- `[space]Justin Alba`
- `Justin[space]`
- `[space]Justin`

Comment: It won't work. A user can trick the server by typing a space after his single-word full name (which by the way is quite common when typing).

Comment: Ok, but simple `John` does not contain any space character and it is `false` then.

Comment: @hsz: OP says **How can i make a validation for full name, so the entered name should contain space?** not sure whether he wants single names too as he has not specified that. Updated the answer for that just in case too.

Comment: @sac i cant get your code to work. It gives me error even if the person have entered correct name e.g "John Andersson".. Heres my code that i used: http://phpbin.net/x/399763185

Comment: @Sarfraz, still same results, getting error even if i typed a full name with space

Comment: I believe that full names in non-Western countries may have no spaces at all, so the OP should have that into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is split the string then check then split string parts.

```
$nameSplit = explode(' ', $name);

if(count($nameSplit) < 2)
{

//Only one name given

}
else
{

  $firstName = trim($nameSplit[0]);
  $secondName = trim($nameSplit[1]);

  if($secondName == '')
  {

    //No second name given

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly have two fields, one for first name and one for surname.

I assume you don't want people with one name to fill in your form so you'd exclude Bono, Eminem, Prince, Sting, Bjork, Enya and a few others.

Comment: I thought of the same argument, but then, those people all have first names and last names like everyone else that they would use when signing up. Still, I agree that insisting on a space is not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah I suppose the contrived-named celebs would have to use their full names in legal contexts. I've just been distracted for a few minutes looking for cultures that only have one name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a test like:

```
$fullName = 'JohnAndersson';

if ( ucfirst(strtolower($fullName)) != ucfirst($fullName) ) {
    echo 'It is not valid';
}
```

`ucfirst(strtolower($fullName))` will convert your string to `Johnandersson` and it is not equals to `JohnAndersson` so it should contains a space.

Comment: What if the user enters 'Johnandersson'? Your solution doesn't work.

Comment: An how you can recognize that it is not just a werid name ?

Comment: +1, this is actually more bulletproof (as far this can be) that the accepted solution.